# MQL4 (Metatrader 4 prog language) OrderSend() , take profit and stop loss variables

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4, metatrader5

```
if (Ask > highest_price) { 

double takeprofit=NormalizeDouble(Bid+15*Point,Digits); 

double stoploss=NormalizeDouble(Bid-5*Point,Digits); 

int ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,0.1, Ask,0,stoploss,takeprofit,"My order",0,0,clrGreen); }
```

Currently this is my code. I want to use custom stop loss and take profit for 5 pips and 15 pips respectively. But i get an error code 130 which is related to that. It only allows me to use the MarketInfo() (eg. the minimum required distance from the price which is actually 0 for EURUSD) to specify take profit and stop loss levels which it does not work with my strategy at all.

I will appreciate your opinion on that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 15 Point does not necessary mean 15 pips. If your broker has 5-digit quotes, 15*Point will mean 1.5 pips and that might be too short to the current price.
Next, it is always easier to print the values before asking us. So try to see all values (Bid, Ask, stop loss, take profit) and it might be easy to see the problem.
Last suggestion is that your broker is a ECN broker or behaves like the one. In such a case, try to `int ticket=OrderSend(_Symbol,OP_BUY,0.1,Ask,10/*slippage in Point*/,0,0,NULL)` and if ok then modify it by placing stoploss and take profit